# How to reuse createApp() method in Vue Server Side rendering

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ejs, server-side-rendering

I have an ejs file excerpt that is as follows:

```
<body>
    <% var test = "App"; %>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <% if (environment === 'production') { %>
    <script type="module" src="<%= manifest['main.ts'].file %>"></script>
    <% } else { %>
    <script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/@vite/client"></script>
    <script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/main.ts"></script> <!--line in question-->
    <% } %>
  </body>
```

this uses server side rendering to run main.ts, which is as follows

```
import { createSSRApp } from 'vue'
import App from "./src/views/App.vue"

createSSRApp(App).mount('#app')
```

I obviously need to access different .vue files other than App.vue, but that would mean creating several different versions of the main.ts file, all pointing to seperate .vue files. This seems incredibly redundant and inefficient. How can I change what .vue file main.ts is pointing to based on some information in the .ejs file?

I attempted to import App.vue directly into the .ejs file but nothing rendered because the app wasn't mounted.

If there is a fundamental flaw in my rendering method, don't hesitate to call it out. Everything works in this format but I don't see how this can scale.

Comment: so, you have multiple `.ejs` files, and you want them to "use" different `.vue` files?

Comment: perhaps add something as a searchParam where you load `main.ts` - of course you'll need to rewrite main.ts to use Dynamic Import (and I don't know if that would work at all with typescript anyway)